# Why 1 Divided 1/3 will result infinity Android Studio

Tags: android, math, infinity

im trying to calculate some value but the result is infinity :

```
double a;
a=1/3;
result=1/(a);
Log.e("Result a : ", String.valueOf(result));
```

Result Log

```
Result a : Infinity
```

why the result infinity? im try this code on excel and the result is 3,
anyone can solved this problem?

**ANSWER** from **Good Luck** Thanks
**1/3** error because its **integer**, 
just change to be **1.0/3.0** and Problem Solved

Comment: you are not using int only right. because (1/3) = 0 when you use int.

Comment: In integer math, `1 / 3 = 0`.

Comment: Please include the declarations for the a and result variables – are they doubles or floats? What do you get when you print out both a and the result?

Comment: **Correct** : Im using Double for Declare Variable a

Comment: and what is your result veritable datatype.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you have a=1/3, a becomes zero because it is the division of two integer numbers. If you want to get the double result (i.e. 0.3333), you should change the code to a=1.0/3.0.

Comment: Variable a is **double**

Comment: a is double but `1` and `3` are **integers**..!!

Comment: if you would  have double a=1.0/3.0, it works too. double and float work similarly here.

Comment: @F_X, `a` might be declared as a double but you store the value of an int divided by an int so the result will be an int, stored in a double

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes you right, it must be 1.0/3.0 for avoid infinitty! Thanks